# Resize bitmap inside a drawable layer-list 2

Tags: android, android-activity, styles

How to scale the bitmap like android:scaleType="fitCenter" ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/gradient"/>
    <item android:bottom="60dip">
        <bitmap
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                android:src="@drawable/image"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I have 680x120px image, and the image does not fit on the small screen. I've been experimenting with gravity, but it didn't help me (for example, I saw the image 240x120, but not 240x42).  I use this style for activity background and I can't to use an ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use **< LinearLayout >** try to use it with your approach.

Comment: I want to use theme:  <style name="MYAPP.Theme" parent="@android:style/Theme">

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here but i solve this problem with gravity fill horizontal and the second most important thing is that you have to use square image/png like 240p X 240p then the picture will automatically resize to its screen.

```
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/back">

</item>

<item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal"

            android:tileMode="disabled"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"/>

</item>
```